# Pod Repo Push not working in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I have created sample CocoaPod file and it worked successfully, now on final stage when I am doing Pod Repo Push it showing me error. Below are the command and error which I am getting.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
s.name         = "IDFVSample"
s.version      = "1.0.0"
s.summary      = "A short description of VFIDOneFramework. Please check this awesome work from me you will like it"
s.description  = "This is the best tutorial. Recently given presentation in the world great forum for the member."
s.homepage     = "https://github.com/kashiftriffort/IDFVSample"
s.license      = "MIT"
s.author       = { "KJilani" => "Kashif.triffort@gmail.com" }
s.platform     = :ios, "9.0"
s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/kashiftriffort/IDFVSample.git", :tag => "1.0.0" }
s.source_files = "IDFVSample/IDFVSample/IDFVSample.swift"
s.dependency 'Firebase/Core'
end

pod repo push IDFVPodSpecs IDFVSample.podspec --allow-warnings

Validating spec
Cloning spec repo `-1` from ``
[!] Unable to add a source with url `` named `-1`.
You can try adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.
```

Comment: Please, provide your `IDFVSample.podspec`

Comment: I have provided IDFVSample.podspec please help me

Comment: Are you trying to push in a private repo or to the main cocoa pods repo?

Comment: I have created a public repository for only pod update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have not added the repo containing your specs yet.
Do something like:

```
pod repo add IDFVSample <git source>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your `IDFVSample.podspec` to the root of your repository(where is already located LICENSE and README files)